# Center Div Expanding Border

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an image grid and want to create an effect similar to this http://instagram.com/instagram/ (the images in the squares on the lower part of the page where the border expands. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="page-title"> </div>

<div id="wrapper" style="min-height:300px;">
  <!--start: Container -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-left:100px;">

        <div style="position: absolute; width:200px; border: 1px solid black; height:200px;">
            <div style="position: relative; background:url('/testimages/1354189822.jpg')" class="polaroids">
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
    .polaroids { 
        background: #fff; 
        float: left; 
        width: 158px;
        height:158px; 
        padding: 5px 5px 5px; 
        text-align: center; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: #333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        border: 4px solid white;
         background-color: black; 
   background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    }

    .polaroids:hover {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
        z-index: 5; border-top: 10px solid white; 
        border-bottom: 10px solid white; 
        border-left: 8px solid white; 
        border-right: 8px solid white;
    }​
```

The middle div does not seem to want to centre. Where am I going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/b5XDK/​​​

Comment: a fiddle will help us to see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, there's one now. It wouldn't let me post the link before for some reason :/

Answer (score 3):

for horizontal center use `margin:0 auto;` on the child element and remove the `float:left;`

http://jsfiddle.net/roine/b5XDK/10/

Answer (score 3):

remove this

```
.polaroids { float:left }
```

Answer (score 2):

remove your `float:left` of .polaroids